# Does SQL Server support shard?

Tags: sql-server, sharding

Any shard ability with SQL server 2008?

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, but with enterprise license. So you're looking at somewhere between 20K to 30K for one.

Answer (score 1):

Check this project in [codeplex](http://enzosqlshard.codeplex.com/).

**SQL Server and SQL Azure Shard Library**

> This library provides a Shard
>   technology that allows you to spread
>   the load of database queries over
>   multiple databases easily (SQL Server
>   and SQL Azure). Uses the Task Parallel
>   Library (TPL) and caching for high
>   performance.

Comment: Unfortunatelly that one is now a dead link.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the SQL Server and SQL Azure Shard Library is not sharding. In my mind, sharding involves rebalancing the data on the nodes while they are *online*, and the above only blasts SQL at the databases and collects the results.  Rebalancing your data is still up to you to do yourself.

Gizzard seems to shard (including rebalancing of the data), though it is JVM based. https://github.com/twitter/gizzard

I still haven't found a good option for sharding with .Net and SQL Server.

Comment: The Enzo SQL Shard has been updated with 2 new sharding strategies along with additional documentation. The latest version provides a sharding strategy for SaaS/multitenant applications. Here is the link: http://enzosqlshard.codeplex.com

Comment: What do you call rebalancing? Are you referring to the Federations feature that allows you to perform an online SPLIT of the data? If so, this doesn't apply to the Enzo library. The Enzo library doesn't work with ranges, like Federations. Rebalancing is something you deal with when one of the databases contains a range of customers, and you need a way to distribute your data differently. The Enzo library works by pointing each customer key to a given database container, so the data is already split at its maximum by design. I am curious to get more feedback on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it support shard, but not like NoSQL.

**NoSQL**: NoSQL shard data based on rows, i.e. lets assume DB table has 100 rows, then DB1 can have 40 rows and DB2 can have 60 rows, as we know data stored in NoSQL in demoralized form.

**SQL**: In SQL you can not easily shard table data, when you shard table then you have to save its reference table as well in single DB.

Lets assume we have multiple shops in a city, then product sold from each shop can be stores in different DB i.e. shard, but Product table may be reference to all shops in the city i.e. each shops may require complete list of all products.